# Changing attribute outside of traitsui GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, traits, traitsui

i have a question about changing the attributes of traitsui GUI.
For the Gui i want to change an attribute of the gui, not because of a change within the GUI.

```
from traits.api import HasTraits, Bool, Int
from traitsui.api import View, Handler

class TC_Handler(Handler):
    None

class TestClass(HasTraits):
    b1 = Int
    b2 = Bool
    b3 = Bool

    def _b1_default(self):
        return 10


view1 = View('b1', 'b2', 'b3',
         title="Alter Title",
         handler=TC_Handler(),
         buttons = ['OK', 'Cancel'])

tc = TestClass()
tc.configure_traits(view=view1)
tc.b1 = 454
```

You see i tried to change the value of b1.

```
tc.b1 = 454
```

change the value, but after closing the window. And i need the change while the gui is running.

Can please someone help?

Thanks

Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GUI.invoke_later` for what you're describing.

```
model_object = get_new_model_object()

from pyface.api import GUI
_gui = GUI()
_gui.invoke_later( lambda : callable(model_object, *args) )

model_object.configure_traits()
```

But be wary that this is not what GUIs are built to do. You've given no hint of why you want to do this. It would be helpful to know why you want to do this because it's quite possible there is a better way of doing whatever it is you want.